# Como utilizar o for no Javascript para exibir galeria de fotos

Tags: javascript, html, css, for, javascript-eventos

Então, ainda sou bem fraquinho em javascript..
Estou procurando aprender mais.

É um codigo bem simples, sao duas "div", div miniatura e div maximizado, meu codigo CSS exibe em um banner flutuante a div maximizado quando eu clico em uma das li dentro da .

Porem ele só exibe a ultima imagem da lista.
Não estou sabendo estruturar o meu for de modo que mostre justamente a imagem cliacada na li.

Eu testei o codigo sem utilizar a estrutura for e funcionou, mas preciso do for pois vou trabalhar com diversas imagens.

Esse é meu javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.sairFoto').click(function(){
        $('#maximizada').fadeOut(500);
    });
    $('#miniatura ul li').click(function(){
        $('#maximizada').fadeIn(500);
    }); 

    for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        $('.foto'+ i ).click(function(){
            document.getElementById("imgMax").src = "fotos/img"+ i +".jpg"; 
        });         
    };
});
</script>


<div id="galeria">
    <div id="maximizada">
        <div class="sairFoto">X</div>
        <img id="imgMax" src="fotos/img1.jpg" />        
    </div>

    <div id="miniatura">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="fotos/img1.jpg" class="foto1" /></li>
                <li><img src="fotos/img2.jpg" class="foto2" /></li>
                <li><img src="fotos/img3.jpg" class="foto3" /></li>
                <li><img src="fotos/img4.jpg" class="foto4" /></li>
                ....

                <li><img src="fotos/img100.jpg" class="foto100"/></li>          
            </ul>           

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que quando você cria o evento de cada elemento, a variável `i` dentro da função é a mesma utilizada dentro do laço `for`.

Isso significa que ao final da estrutura de repetição, a variável terá em todas as funções o último valor que no caso é `99`. Veja o exemplo abaixo para entender melhor:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    function show_number() {
        // A variável "i" é a mesma que "i" do laço for. 
        // Logo, a variável aqui dentro sofrerá alterações.
        console.log(i); 
    }
}

show_number();
```

O que você pode fazer é obter o elemento em que você clicou utilizando `$(this)`, para assim conseguir o atributo `src` do próprio elemento. Veja como ficaria o código:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    $('.foto' + i ).click(function() {
        const src = $(this).attr("src");
        document.getElementById("imgMax").src = src; 
    });         
}
```

Comment: Shooow ! Muito obrigado pela resposta.